# issues woocommerce add_to_cart with data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an issue when I'm trying to set a data into my item:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', '_add_custom_item_data', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', '_get_cart_item_from_session', 10, 2);

function _add_custom_item_data($cart_item_data, $product_id){
    if(!empty($cart_item_data)){
        $cart_item_data['custom_field'] = 'aaaa';
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
function _get_cart_item_from_session($cart_item, $values){
    if (isset($values['custom_field'])) {
            $cart_item['custom_field'] = $values['custom_field'];
        }
    return $cart_item;
}
```

when I use:

```
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($id,'1','','',array('_my_data','000000000000000000000000000000'));
```

the _add_custom_item_data function is executed as well and I have the _my_data variable.

but i'm try to get the variable with my product:

```
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
foreach($items as $item){
    echo $woocommerce->cart->get_item_data( $item ) . "<br>";
}
```

I didn't see my variable...

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

At last function try following to get data

```
<?php 
                $cart = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
                $items = 0;
                $total = 0;
                foreach ($cart as $p) {
                    $total += $p['line_total'];
                    $items += $p['quantity'];
                }
                echo $items;
                echo $total;
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of assigning data directly to an index you should assign it to `product_meta` first, for example, you can try this

```
$item_meta['your_key] = 'your_value';
$cart_item_data ['product_meta'] = array('meta_data' => $item_meta);
```